# BPM frameworks in PHP?

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks, business-process-management

Do we have any BPM frameworks developed in PHP?

I did a Google and found some old (2005) entires which talk about starting such a project. But I don't see any solid framework out and running. So, I was just curious.. do we have any?

If not, why haven't the community yet developed one? Zend framework is a leading PHP framework, why haven't they started developing such a component?

Comment: What is BPM? If you mean http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_process_management,  it goes way beyond a simple web module.

Comment: Yes, I agree.. i am not an expert on PHP, so the above question might be wrong. But I don't see anything like jBPM,uEngine etc or a BPEL engine in PHP..

Comment: I would also like to add workflow engines, etc

Comment: Zend is a framework like you say - it doesn't come with pre-built modules, it's there for you to build modules with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check EzerPHP out. Very promising.
code.google.com/p/ezerphp/

Comment: thanks for the link.. EzerPHP looks interesting.. but how good is the support for it in community?

Answer (score 2):

Most of the relevant BPMN 2.0 based Open Source Process Engines are written in Java (e.g. Activiti, Camunda, jBPM, Bonita). If you would like to integrate such an Engine into your PHP-Application, you could use the REST-APIs of those Engines. With this approach, you could use proven BPM-Engines within your PHP application. In addition, you have benefits like active communities, stable code etc.

Could this be an adequate alternative for your usecase?

Answer (score 1):

We have developed a new BPM framework from the ground using PHP called **Process Companion**. It is based on the BPMN 2.0 standard. Get more information at http://www.processcompanion.com

Comment: it is not open source

Answer (score -1):

https://code.google.com/p/hush-framework/
Here is another choice, very fit. The only problem is it's description is in Chinese.
BTW. I'm a Chinese lol.